# Grant access to Amazon S3 bucket only to one IAM User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I wish to have a bucket that only one IAM user could access using the AWS Console, list its content and access object files inside it.

So, I have created the IAM user, the bucket itself, and later:

bucket policy as follow:

```
{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "statement1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::0000000:user/dave"
                },
                "Action": [
                    "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                    "s3:ListBucket"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket1234"
            },
            {
                "Sid": "statement2",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::0000000:user/dave"
                },
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket1234/*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

And also a inline policy attached to my user's group, as follow:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*Object",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket1234/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now: I can list my buckets, access the desired bucket, list its content (so far so good). The problem is when I try to open one file object inside the bucket and I get "access denied" error. If I turn the object public, I can access it, but I can also access it using other IAM accounts, and that is not the intention. I want to access the bucket, list its contents and access objects only by usage of this specific IAM account. What am I doing wrong? How can I reach this goal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What S3 permissions have been granted to other users? Do they have any policies that grant access to _all_ S3 buckets?

Comment: Hello @JohnRotenstein, actually I do only have these policies I had described. And public access was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

By default, no IAM User can access any bucket. It is only by granting permissions to users that they can access resources.

However, many people tend to grant Amazon S3 permissions for *all* buckets, at least for Administrators. This then makes it difficult to *remove* permissions so that a bucket can only be accessed by one user. While it can be done with `Deny` policies, such policies are difficult to craft correctly.

For situations where specific data should only be accessed by one user, or a specific group of users (eg HR staff), I would recommend that you **create a separate AWS Account and only grant permission to specific IAM Users or IAM Groups via a Bucket Policy** (which works fine cross-account). This way, any generic policies that grant access to "all buckets" will not apply to buckets in this separate account.

---

**Update: Accessing private objects**

Expanding on what is mentioned in the comments below, a private object in Amazon S3 can be accessed by an authorized user. However, when accessing the object, it is necessary to identify *who* is accessing the object and their identity must be proved. This can be done in one of several ways:

- In the **Amazon S3 management console**, use the **Open** command (in the **Actions** menu). This will open the object using a pre-signed URL that authorizes the access based upon the user who logged into the console. The same method is used for the **Download** option.
- Using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), you can download objects. The AWS CLI needs to be pre-configured with your IAM security credentials to prove your identity.
- Programs using an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) can access S3 objects using their IAM security credentials. In fact, the AWS CLI is simply a Python program that uses the AWS SDK.
- If you want to **access the object via a URL**, an application can generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). This URL includes the user's identity and a security signature that grants access to a private object for a limited period (eg 5 minutes). This method is commonly used when web applications want to grant access to a private object, such as a document or photo. The S3 management console actually uses this method when a user selects Actions/Open, so that the user can view a private object in their browser.

Comment: Hello John, actually I am getting denied, and that is the problem. My bucket policy is working fine (only the desired user is able to list bucket's content)..the problem is, my IAM user cannot read any file object inside the bucket, I can only make it work turning file object public, but it does not satisfy me, as other IAM user will be able to access it as well. So, I need to maintain my bucket managing and listing working as it is for now, but also I need to enable this IAM to read and open files inside the bucket. For now, it is getting access denied when I try to open any of them

Comment: You should only need to create an Inline Policy for the IAM User. There is no need to create a Bucket Policy, since the IAM Policy is sufficient (and more appropriate because it is only for one user). How are you accessing the object -- are you doing it via the Amazon S3 management console? What exactly are you clicking and where does it say Access Denied? I'm wondering whether the console needs a few more permissions, such as `GetObjectAcl`?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it via AWS Console, using web browser. I can list the buckets, open the desired one, list object files inside it. But when I click at the weblink for one of the file objects and try to open it in the browser (read a .txt file for example), it shows the XML file saying "access denied". The only way I can open the file is turning it into public, which I do not actually want as I need to protect it from others. All seems good, except for the fact that I cannot open object file itself. I do not know what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: There are two ways to "open" a file from the S3 management console. One way just provided an anonymous URL, which only works if the object is public. The other way is to use "Actions / Open", which creates a pre-signed URL that includes your identity information -- this will provide access to a private object. The same thing goes for the "Download" option -- it will generate a pre-signed URL that lets you download a private object. Try those options and see whether you have access.

Comment: Thank you, John. So, the only way to actually open/view file content in the web console is to download the file and opening in my computer? To make it accessible via browser (like a page) the only way is to prior make it public?? Am I getting it correct? I was able to get the file like you said (actually downloading it using DOWNLOAD option in the console).

Comment: I have added more details to my answer.